# PCRE RegEx difference between PHP and MariaDB

Tags: php, regex, mariadb, pcre

I have a RegEx that does not match using PHP (nor regex101.com) but does with MariaDB. Its purpose is to search for HTML classes in XML values (the HTML is encoded).

Here is an example XML value where you can see a `<ul>` element with a `liste--non-ordonnee--gros--exergue` CSS class:

```xml
&lt;ul class=&quot;liste--non-ordonnee--gros--exergue&quot;&gt;
```

I want the RegEx to match only full classes. Therefore if I search `--exergue` I don't want it to match.
Using PHP or other PCRE/PCRE2 online tester it does not match:

```
~(class=&quot;(?:[^&]*\s)?)--exergue~sU
```

But using MariaDB (v10.2.40 - PCRE 8.42), it matches:

```
(?sU)(class=&quot;(?:[^&]*\s)?)--exergue
```

It looks for a `class` attribute containing the class to replace. I tried to change the class name to something else for demonstration purposes (searching `--suffix` in `class-with--suffix`) but then it would not match anymore on the MariaDB version.

What is wrong with my RegEx or its MariaDB version ?

> I am aware that regular expressions should not be used with HTML and am open to alternatives but this is TYPO3: storing encoded HTML into XML values in a db column. Design changes require massive class renaming.

Comment: Can you create a MCVE that doesn't involve XML etc., what's the simplest possible (mis)match you can produce?

Comment: @MarkusAO I removed the XML part. I can't really remove the HTML `class` attribute, it would just leave the CSS classes.

Comment: Thanks. For reference, your regex in PHP: https://3v4l.org/mVUWH (no match), and the SQL; `SELECT '&lt;ul class=&quot;liste--non-ordonnee--gros--exergue&quot;&gt;' REGEXP '(?sU)(class=&quot;(?:[^&]*\s)?)--exergue';` -- which does match on MariaDB (10.3.11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the very short MCVE of your case:

```
SELECT 'class=&quot;s--e' REGEXP '(?sU)(class=&quot;(?:[^&]*\s)?)--e'
```

MariaDB matches, PHP doesn't match ([demo](https://3v4l.org/4YU2Q)). Why? As in MariaDB's manual for [REGEXP](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp/):

> Note: Because MariaDB uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, "\n" to represent the newline character), you must double any "`\`" that you use in your REGEXP strings.

Your issue is caused by the `\s` that should be double-escaped as `\\s` in your MariaDB query. Once you fix that, the PHP and SQL regex statements become equivalent and behave the same.

This *won't* match (with `--e` not led by space):

```
SELECT 'class=&quot;s--e' REGEXP '(?sU)(class=&quot;(?:[^&]*\\s)?)--e';
```

This *will* match (with  `--e` led by space):

```
SELECT 'class=&quot;s --e' REGEXP '(?sU)(class=&quot;(?:[^&]*\\s)?)--e';
```

Comment: The question is about the PHP and not the  MariaDB syntax. Read slowly.

Comment: @MartinZeitler perhaps you can also read it again. OP asks about the _diverging behavior between the apparently identical PHP and MariaDB regular expressions_. This difference of behavior is a result of incorrect (non-doubled) escape character in his SQL. The expected result is _no match unless class name is preceded by `\s` space_.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thanks for the answer. It feels strange to *double-escape* metacharacters but at least it works. As the SQL query is built from PHP I had to *"triple-escape"* the metacharacters.